# when padding I receive this error Dimension -343776 must be >= 0 [Op:Fill]

Tags: python, tensorflow

When trying to pad the audio data by this code, I receive the error in the title

```
zero_padding = tf.zeros([48000] - tf.shape(waveform), dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: Hello user7823094978, please also include the error in the question itself. You can also post the whole colored trace with `python-traceback`. Look [here](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports) for more info. If my answer does not fit you, please upload or create a sample waveform so we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome! Have you checked the value of `tf.shape(waveform)`? It is probably 43776 + 48000 = 391776.

Here is the code to reproduce the error:

```py
tf.zeros([48000] - tf.shape(tf.zeros(391776)), dtype=tf.float32)
```